# Table of Figures loses format after 9th figure (see attached image)

Tags: floats, table-of-contents

[image: Screenshot of Table of Figure Issue]

How would I fix this issue to add a space in between the caption and figure number.

Comment: Please confirm that you use LaTeX to compile your document. If that's the case, please also provide some information about how the Table of Contents and the List of Figures are organized. E.g., do you use the `tocloft` package? If so, please edit your posting to provide the code you employ.

Comment: Yes i am using overleaf. I will include code. Using the tocloft package does not solve the issue

Comment: @Mico post was tagged as duplicate and I was able to fix it with the tocloft package "
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike} %the previous line resets it